# How to perform addition operation for a column in a loop in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i am having 2 models where **User has_many invoice_details** and **InvoiceDetail belongs_to user**. 
Now, i am having a condition where we have to perform addition for a column named total_amount which is in a loop.

```
<% if @user.invoice_details.nil?  %>
           "NA"
         <% else %>
<% @user.invoice_details.each do |mg| %>
<%= mg.total_amount %>
<% end %>
<%end%>
```

It is displaying amounts *222 333*, i want to display the value as **555** (222 + 333)

Comment: why is total amount a string field to begin with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A the User model you can calculate invoice_details total_amount

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :invoice_details

 def total_invoices_amount
    #convert string to integer and sum
   self.invoice_details.map{|x| x.total_amount.to_i}.sum   
 end
end
```

Than at UI you can get `total_invoices_amount`

```
<%= @user.total_invoices_amount%>
```

Comment: Use `compact`,  `self.invoice_details.map(&:total_amount).compact.sum`

Comment: @Masud : I tried your answer, i am getting 222333 instead of 555

Comment: @sachingod, Is total_amount is string? If so, than convert to Integer and sum.

Comment: @Masud - Yeah, it's a string

Comment: You can avoid the double map and compact. `self.invoice_details.map{|d| d.total_amount ? d.total_amount.to_i : 0}.sum`

Comment: @Santhosh, Yes, double map is not necessary. Thanks for suggestion.

Comment: @Salil, `compact` method is not needed. `to_i` method can also convert `nil` to `0`.

Comment: yeah, We need `compact` in case if it is a `integer`

Answer (score 1):

It will automatically take care for `nil` case

```
@user.invoice_details.sum(:total_amount)
```

Comment: total_amount is string field so it would throw error.

Comment: If it is then Please add migration to change it into integer

Answer (score 1):

**Fix 1** :
The ruby way of doing it but i insist don't do this

```
<% if @user.invoice_details.nil?  %>
  "NA"
<% else %>
  <%= @user.invoice_details.map(&:total_amount).sum %>
<%end%>
```

**Fix 2** :
Do it in your model where you query it it will be much faster ie sum it using db query.

Put below method in the User model .

```
def sum_invoices_amount
  self.invoice_details.sum(:total_amount)
end
```

And use it in the view

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `map`, it's bad, you're querying for all objects then looping on them and adding the amount, and you'll feel it when the invoices start to increase in number, instead let the database calculate the sum for you, with a single query, also create the method into the model to separate the logic from the view.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def total_invoices_amount
     invoice_details.sum(:total_amount)
  end
end
```

Then in the view you'll just access that method

```
<%= @user.total_invoices_amount %>
```

You'll also notice the difference in the sql query that's running, assuming the user id = 1:

the the activerecord sum will do:

```
SELECT SUM(`invoice_details`.`total_amount`) AS sum_id FROM `invoice_details`  WHERE `invoice_details`.`user_id` =  1
```

which returns a single `Fixnum` number ( and zero if the records don't even exist )

But the map will do

```
SELECT `invoice_details`.`*` FROM `invoice_details`  WHERE `invoice_details`.`user_id` =  1
```

Returns an `ActiveRecord::Relation` that maps to an N number of records depending on the number of invoices the user has.

**Update:**
Ok, I just noticed you have the field as string, which is weird considering it's a total amount field, anyways you'll need to tweak the method a little bit, we could also let mysql ( assuming you are using mysql ) cast the string to integer before doing the sum.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def total_invoices_amount
     invoice_details.select('sum(cast(total_amount as signed)) as total_amount').first.total_amount
  end
end
```

Comment: total_amount is string field so it would throw error.

Comment: ok, well that's a weird way to implement a total amount field

Comment: @AnilSingh I've updated my answer with a casting method for the string field, though I believe it's just better for the OP to convert the field to integer, but I'll assume he has his reasons.